# MongoDB Gridfs-stream is Only Deleting the File but Not the Chunk

Tags: javascript, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am trying to delete a file and chunk from my MongoDB database but my route only deletes the file but not the chunk. I've seen a few StackOverflow solutions to this issue but they are either now outdated or are based on the deprecated `remove()` function. I saw another solution that claimed that adding `root: bucketName` to the delete query options fixes this issue, but it didn't for me.

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
const { authUser } = require("../middleware/auth");
const uploadMulter = require("../middleware/upload");
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");

const connection = mongoose.connection;

let gfs, gridfsBucket;

connection.once("open", () => {
  gfs = Grid(connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
});

router.delete("/files/:_id", (req, res) => {

  gfs
    .collection("profilePictures")
    .deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.params._id) }, (err) => {});//only deletes the profilePicture.file, but not profilePicture.chunk
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that using `delete()` removes both the chunk and file but it must be ran on the [gridfsBucket](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/gridfsbucket.html#delete). All other "solutions" on StackOverflow use either the deprecated `remove()` or `deleteOne()`on `gfs`.

The issue with this solution is that the `delete()` function only works with `BSON _id's` so If you would like to delete files based on filename or metadata then It wont work.

```js
router.delete("/files/:_id", (req, res) => {
  gridfsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(connection.db, {
    bucketName: "profilePictures",
  });
  gridfsBucket.delete(ObjectId(req.params._id));
});
```